# Domain hosting IP address

Tags: dns

Can I have a domain hosted with two different IP addresses? I recently was trying to get my domain hosting company to allocate two different IP addresses to my domain and I was told this was not possible. I wanted to transition from one ISP to another without having service downtime or any problems so that I could fall back in case of any challenges.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It is absolutely possible for a single domain to be hosted on two different IP addresses.  For example, take google.com:

```
$ dig www.google.com +noall +answer
www.google.com.         29      IN      A       64.233.168.106
www.google.com.         29      IN      A       64.233.168.147
www.google.com.         29      IN      A       64.233.168.99
www.google.com.         29      IN      A       64.233.168.103
www.google.com.         29      IN      A       64.233.168.104
www.google.com.         29      IN      A       64.233.168.105
```

You're probably running into issues with your DNS host having a policy against it.  And/or your web host thinking you mean to have two different IP addresses pointing to the same web server (which doesn't make sense, or accomplish anything).

If you do happen to get your DNS host to advertise two IP addresses for two different Web Servers hosted at two different companies for your single domain, keep in mind the toll that will play on the users session.  Approximately half your *connections* will go to one host, and the other half will go to the other.  Notice I said *connections*, not *users*.  It is very possible (and likely) that even a single user's session will end up sending packets to both web servers.  Which means every few clicks your users will loose all their session information (shopping carts, log in cookies, etc)

Comment: This could potentially be solved by making the old server a proxy for the new one. A better solution would be to setup a high availability solution for the transition, having all traffic go through a VIP that forwards the traffic to whichever server is up. There are public  services that do that, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no.

When an IP application does a dns lookup the server can only return one IP address.

Comment: Thats not true.  Try doing a lookup of google.com.